# find and edit a txt file with a batch program

Tags: batch-file, find, edit

I want to edit a txt file with a batch script.
I have looked online and tried to adjust some examples to suit my needs.
However I have no programing skills and have not been able to get my program to work.

Here is my problem.
I have a txt file which contains this at some point in the file:

```
Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue
  321043      1     2.124238E+00
  321043      2     2.169874E+00
  321043      3     2.628187E+00
  321043      4     2.832127E+00
  321043      5     2.968359E+00
  321043      6     3.131774E+00
```

I want to change it to look like this:

```
R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S

Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue
  321043      1     2.630623E-01
  321043      2     2.676471E-01
  321043      3     2.982211E-01
```

So basically add "R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S" two lines before "Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue", but without deleting whats in the lines before. i.e add two new lines in.

I have tried the following, but it only printed out the first 8 lines to the new text file

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (le_panel_7_cut down_i.out) do call :Change "%%a"
exit /b

:Change
set Text=%~1
if "%Text%"=="Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue" (
(echo R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S &echo[ &echo[ &echo[Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue)>> D:\FEA\newfile.txt
) else (
(echo %Text%)>> D:\FEA\newfile.out
)
exit /b
```

I also tried another script which looked like this, but this didn't work either.

```
  @echo on
        SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

          for /f "delims=" %%a in (le_panel_7_cut_down_i.out) do (
            set foo=%%a
            if !foo!=="Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue" set foo=(
echo R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S &echo[ &echo[ &echo[Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue) 
     echo !foo! >> file3.txt)
```

If someone to correct my script it would be much appreciated.
Regards
Iain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%z IN (' type eigenfile.txt^|findstr /n /r "$" ') DO (
  SET "line=%%z"
  SET "line=!line:*:=!"
  IF "!line!"=="Subcase  Mode  Buckling Eigenvalue" (
   ECHO(R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S
   ECHO(
  )
  ECHO(!line!
 )
)>outfile.txt

FC eigenfile.txt outfile.txt

GOTO :eof
```

This should execute your revised specification.

Essentially, it simply reproduces each line, including empty lines (the reason for the `FINDSTR /n` and the following `SET ...!..:*:=!"` which removes the line-number prefixed by the `findstr`). When it finds the target line, it first adds the extra two lines specified.

Note that `echo(` has been proved to be the best choice of the various `ECHO` variants to allow for instance, an empty variable, to be reproduced correctly.

I've assumed obviously that your data is in `eigenfile.txt`. This batch produces `outfile.txt` - your option to rename it - and the FC is simply to show the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add two lines at the beginning of yourfile.txt, try this:

```
echo R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S >newfile.txt
echo. >>newfile.txt
type yourfile.txt >>newfile.txt

delete yourfile.txt
rename newfile.txt yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear
I don't want to anything to the begin of the file.
I need the program to search to where "Subcase Mode Buckling Eigenvalue" is located in the file, then add "R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S" two lines above. the text "Subcase Mode Buckling Eigenvalue"  will be several hundred lines into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I misunderstood your question, but:

```
@echo off
echo R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S > out.tmp
echo. >> out.tmp
type yourtxtfile.txt >> out.tmp
move out.tmp yourtxtfile.txt
```

Is this what you mean?